# Users named "facebook-1234567890"

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, display-names, facebook

There are apparently a lot of user accounts being created on Stack Exchange sites who are named `facebook-` followed by their numeric Facebook user ID.

There are over a thousand such users on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=facebook-

I'm guessing this is a bug in the feature to log in with Facebook? Presumably it should be using their real name, or a generated default name. Naming people after a website is a bit mad.

Answer (score 6):

I took a look at the numbers - both over our entire data set and over recent months.

They all agree - around 0.1% of the users who user facebook end up with a `facebook-#######` display name.

I couldn't reproduce this issue in my testing, so couldn't find a commonality here (though a bunch were spammer accounts).

<strike>This doesn't look like something we can fix on our end - we are just using the data coming from facebook.</strike>

Digging more into this, yep, this is an issue on our end (and has been around for a looooong time), I will push a fix in my morning (so I can monitor any issues cropping up from such a change).

Comment: Will it also fix the names of those 0.1% affected by the bug?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - my intention is to fix the bug that caused these names - so they no longer occur. Adjusting the current ones is a very different thing.

Comment: Fair enough, so will you also do this? Not that I really care personally, but guess those affected might. Thanks anyway, guess it's never too late to hunt down bugs! :)

Comment: Haven't figured out if we will. Probably.

Comment: I'm not *too* worried about adjusting existing usernames since anyone can edit their display name. If anyone has a privacy concern, there's an easy fix available to them. Granted, they may not be aware of the full implications, but the risk here seems relatively minimal to me.

Comment: Even if you're not going to change the existing names to the users' real names, would it make sense to reset them to Stack Exchange "user123456"-style names, so we don't have a lot of users named "facebook"?